# How do I change the shape of an object while keeping all of its data?

Tags: python, game-engine

This is my first time making a game in Blender and I've been using the cube that is the first thing on your screen as my player. The player has a bunch of code in it now and I want it to be a different shape, not a cube. How do I change it without having to rewrite all of its insides?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different methods.

## Switch the meshes

Select your cube. In the **Data** panel, the first field allows you to select another mesh :
[image: data panel]

The *object* data will be preserved (logic bricks, modifiers, etc). Only the *mesh* data will be affected (vertex groups, materials slots, etc)

## Use parenting

This method is preferable if your character already has an armature, and allows to keep the cube Physics settings.

Parent the character to the cube : select the character (or its armature if it has one), keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed, then select the cube, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, select Object.

Make the cube invisible : in its **Physics** panel, tick **Invisible**.

To "hide" the cube in the 3d view but keep it selectable and usable, you can set **Maximum draw type : Wire** in its **Object** panel.

Comment: (And I might precise that the first solution is the best one. Use that one as long as possible.)